# how to send cross domain response

Tags: php

The flow looks quite similar to payment gateway. My project involves sending data from one website to another using post request.

Send website process the data and redirect to domain one.

Now the problem is how to send response from second website to first that data is processes or not with redirection.

Can not use get request because of sensitive data.

Comment: Can you provide any examples of code you've tried and the errors it has generated?  Without clear examples, you don't have a question we can answer.

Comment: I want to know to how to send response back to website one, I don't how to code this part

Comment: You need to learn about REST API. Also, if you are chaining REST services--that is-- website one calls website two then website two returns information to website 1... then you need to learn about Clients as well. You need to produce and consume REST services

Comment: You can read more about the REST API by [clicking here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html).  Please note that writing a tutorial for you is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I meant to say, if you call a REST service inside of your REST service, you probably need to learn about Clients (or the PHP equivalent)

Comment: @PardeepKumar What exactly is the problem? You send a POST request to the server and receive a response from it.